# Filtering RSS feed

Tags: iphone, dictionary, rss

How can i filter a loaded rss feed to display only the category of news that i choose?

I'm putting each item with its components in a NSMutableDictionnary so I can test on the category, but the problem is, in which method should i put my if conditional and how can i display only the cells with the right news and let the other cells disappear

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `NSMutableDictionary` as the datasource for your table view, you could create an `NSArray` that is composed of references to the objects in the dictionary that only contain your specified category.